# SIM800L + TTL Serial to USB Converter interfacing with PC

Tags: java, sms, gsm

As AT-Commands for SMS receiving do not work for many phones I decided to use GSM modem instead so I googled and found SIM800L (please not that L in the end, as this one is a bit cheap) to be the solution. Furthermore, I found out that TTL serial to USB module is required to get it connected to PC (I guess so). Some time ago I have used Java + AT-Commands with some Nokia phone to send SMS but the receiving commands were not supported by the phone.
 Now my questions are: 
Will these circuits (I have very limited knowledge of electronics) connect to the PC and my java program? 
and would I be able to issue AT-Commands from java? 
Plus: Is there any java library for At-Commands which would work with SIM800L to get things a bit simple.